# How to use geom_roc() from ggplot2 with probabilities

Tags: r, ggplot2, roc

I have used the following code to generate a ROC plot

```
library(plotROC)
library(ggplot2)
library(e1071)
library(mlbench)

data(BreastCancer)
BreastCancer$Class <- ifelse(BreastCancer$Class == "malignant",1,0)

bound <- floor((nrow(BreastCancer)/4)*3)         
df <- BreastCancer[sample(nrow(BreastCancer)), ]        
training <- df[1:bound,-1]    
testing <- df[(bound+1):nrow(df), -1] 

nb_mod <- naiveBayes(formula = Class ~ ., data = training)

prob_nb <- predict(nb_mod,testing,type="raw")
df <- data.frame(Class = testing$Class,Prob = prob_nb )

basicplot <- ggplot(df, aes(d = Class, m = Prob.1)) + geom_roc()
```

I am confused as I found the following example in the documentation
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotROC/vignettes/examples.html:
The marker M used as an aesthetic is a value between roughly -2 and 2, not a probability. Am I using the function geom_roc correctly?

```
library(plotROC)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2529)
D.ex <- rbinom(200, size = 1, prob = .5)
M1 <- rnorm(200, mean = D.ex, sd = .65)
M2 <- rnorm(200, mean = D.ex, sd = 1.5)

test <- data.frame(D = D.ex, D.str = c("Healthy", "Ill")[D.ex + 1], 
               M1 = M1, M2 = M2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

basicplot <- ggplot(test, aes(d = D, m = M1)) + geom_roc()
```

Comment: There is a whole paper written about that library, I think you will find your answer there: (https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v079c02)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. No, in that paper he actually uses the same example. He speaks of markers (M1,M2). But these are no probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `d` to numeric and then it works.

```
as.numeric(D)
```